# Como quitar los colores al comando "ls" en zsh

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, wsl

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando realizo el comando de "ls" me aparecen subrayados los ficheros, alguien conoce una solución a este problema

pd: Tambien estoy usando ZSH y Oh my zsh

Answer (score 0):

El comando `ls` tiene una opción para mostrar en color propiedades de los ficheros, si son carpetas, permisos... El objetivo es diferenciarlos a simple vista.

`Zsh` hace un alias para ti, puedes consultarlo:

```
➜  ~ alias ls
ls='ls --color=tty'
➜  ~
```

Explora tu fichero `~/.zshrc` en tu home y quita el comentario `#`

```
# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"
```

Cierra la consola y abrela de nuevo para comprovarlo. El alias ha desaparecido. El comando no se ejecuta con modo color.

```
➜  ~ alias ls
➜  ~
```